# Calabi-Yau moduli space - Kahler metric deformations

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, calabi-yau

On a Calabi-Yau manifold $(M,g)$, we have the requirement of Ricci-flatness of the metric $g$:

$$ R_{\mu \bar{\nu}}[g] = 0 $$

If we look at a deformation of the metric $ g + \delta g$ and impose the Ricci-flatness condition, $R_{\mu \bar{\nu}}[g + \delta g] = 0$, then it is commonly asserted that the deformed metric satisfies the 'Lichnerowicz' condition:

$$ \nabla_{\sigma} \nabla^{\sigma} \delta g_{\mu \nu} + 2 R_{\mu \; \; \nu}^{\; \; \rho \; \; \sigma} \delta g_{\rho \sigma} = 0$$

e.g. this is asserted in page 4, equation (2.1) of this 1991 paper by Candelas et. al. ([1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032139190122E)). I can't seem to derive this expression. By expanding the Ricci tensor to first order in the deformation $\delta g$, I've derived a related expression, which I've also seen in various textbooks, that:

$$\nabla_{\sigma} \nabla^{\sigma} \left(g^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}\right) =0  $$

but I can't seem to reduce the last expression into the Lichnerowicz condition. A quick sketch about how this condition is derived would be very welcome.